# C# DateFormatString for GMT offset

Tags: c#, datetime, json.net, format

I need to consume some JSON with `DateTime` data in a format similar to this:

`Tue Jun 11 00:00:00 +0100 2019`

I believe the +0100 is the GMT offset (+0100 being British Summer Time). I am deserializing this using C# newtonsofts JsonConvert. e.g.

```
List<Staff_Extra> staff_Extras = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Staff_Extra>>(jStaffExtra.ToString(), new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatString = "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy" 
});
```

This throws an exception because of the offset. What should the `DateFormatString` look like to account for this offset?

example code https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDateFormatString.htm

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings I guess you need `K` part.

Comment: add `zzz` for the timezone token part?

Comment: `zzz` @VidmantasBlazevicius has solved the problem! Thank you!

Comment: @sbmobile you are welcome, I've added it as an answer then.

Comment: Careful. `hh` is for a 12-hour clock.  You probably want `HH` for a 24-hour clock.

Comment: You should also consider using a `DateTimeOffset` type instead of a `DateTime` in your data model.  (`zzz` isn't recommended for `DateTime` values.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you want to read that time in as **Converted to your local time**, use

  `DateTime.ParseExact(test, "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy", null);`

  This will return that time as `6/10/2019 5:00:00 PM` (I'm in MDT, US culture)
- If you want to read that time as a **local time and preserve the original timezone**, use

  `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(test, "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy", null);`

  This will return that time as `6/11/2019 12:00:00 AM +01:00` (preserves timezone offset)
- If you want to read that as **local time and ignore the timezone offset**, use:

  `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(test, "ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy", null).DateTime;`

  This will return that time as `6/11/2019 12:00:00 AM`

Answer (score 1):

Add `zzz` for the timezone token part. Other tokens can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).